# Does the MIPS bltzal instruction set r31 even if the condition is not true?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm reading the docs for the MIPS `bltzal` instruction and there I see:

> Place the return address link in GPR 31. The return link is the
>   address of the second instruction following the branch, where
>   execution continues after a procedure call. An 18-bit signed offset
>   (the 16-bit offset field shifted left 2 bits) is added to the address
>   of the instruction following the branch (not the branch itself), in
>   the branch delay slot, to form a PC-relative effective target address.
>   If the contents of GPR rs are less than zero (sign bit is 1), branch
>   to the effective target address after the instruction in the delay
>   slot is executed.

The way I interpret this is that the r31 register is *always* set to the address of the instruction after the delay slot, even if the branch is not taken. Another reference (https://imagination-technologies-cloudfront-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/documentation/MD00086-2B-MIPS32BIS-AFP-05.04.pdf) seems to confirm my thinking. Is my understanding correct or not?

The reason I'm asking is that the ELF MIPS binary I'm looking at has the following two instructions right at the beginning of its entry point:

```
    bltzal r0,skip          ; r0 is never lt 0, so fall into delay slot
    nop                     ; but was r31 set or not?
skip:
    lui    +0x0FC1          ; add 0x0FC08628 to r31
    addui  r28,r28,-0x79D8
    addu   r28,r28,r31
```

which clearly has the intent of taking the address of the instruction of the `skip`-labelled instruction and adding an offset to it, presumably to get to the global offset table (GOT). Since we're comparing `r0` to 0, the branch should never be taken. If the `r31` register isn't assigned, we'd be taking the `r31` set by the caller, which makes the use of the `bltzal` instruction completely redundant -- why bother with it then?

Comment: This: http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html says `ra` is _not_ set _unless_ the branch is taken. This is what makes the most sense. Also, I just ran it in the mars simulator and it did _not_ set `ra`.

Comment: This: https://imagination-technologies-cloudfront-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/documentation/MD00086-2B-MIPS32BIS-AFP-05.04.pdf states that `ra` _is_ set; from the "horse's" mouth. Could the simulator have been programmed incorrectly? Or is the documentation from two sources wrong?

Comment: [MIPS' own documentation](http://www2.engr.arizona.edu/~ece369/Resources/MipsInstructionSetReference.pdf) says it's unconditionally set (see the Operation section). As references go it would seem to be reliable. I'll still try to set up a test with real hardware though since I've checked the source on 2 emulators that do it in two different ways too(!)

Comment: Much appreciated, @JoachimIsaksson. I want this to be accurate when I implement the instruction in the Reko decompiler (https://github.com/uxmal/reko) and the widely differing answers I'm finding on the web are confusing to say the least.

Comment: Another data point: SPIM sets r31 always... but apparently Mars doesn't!

Comment: I'm looking at the mars [java] source and it even has a comment about _conditionally_ setting `ra`. I'm also looking for the MIPS reference that Ken Vollmar used [it is _yet_ another one]--it's either in a source code comment, one of the web pages for mars, or the mars white paper. Another thing to keep in mind: It may be both ways (e.g. older chips circa 1980's may do it one way, and what MIPS says _now_ could be from a chip errata that was done later). If you can't get a definitive answer, you can punt and make it a config option, just like mars defaults branch delays _off_

Comment: After further reasearch, it seems that the glibc runtime for the ELF ABI also assumes that `ra`/`r31` gets set _unconditionally_. It sure is disconcerting that different instances of the MIPS architecture appear to implement the instruction differently! I will leave this question open for a while, and very likely will have to make the behavior of this instruction customizable in the Reko decompiler as @CraigEstey suggests.

Comment: The mars folks welcome feedback. Here's the mars home page: http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/index.htm You might just email either Ken Vollmar or Pete Sanderson, point out the issue, and ask them what they think

Comment: I've sent them an email; I'll post an update here if they reply.